# Can I use "they" to refer to the singular "population"?

Tags: pronouns, reference

Can I use "they" to refer to the singular "population"?

> **An** aging **population** can heavily strain public health systems, a drawback that far
> outweighs any potential benefits **they** may bring, such as the value
> **their** wealth of work experience can add to the workforce.

I wrote the text.

Comment: This isn't a "singular they" usage. It's just blurring the distinction between the singular and plural referents, which I think is rather clumsy for a formal context. As a Brit I'm usually happy with for words like ***couple, pair, police, company*** to have "flexible" plurality, but Americans are more likely to insist all words like that (and by implication, ***a** population*) should always be treated as syntactically singular, so they might have stronger opinions.

Comment: Are you saying that an aging population brings health benefits? That seems like an odd thing to say. The sentence is simply off. However, the aging population can be they. "they" is fine as a pronoun but the sentence needs fixing. And that is in all Englishes.

Comment: You can use either, but normally "it" when it's considered as a single entity (the population as a whole) and "their" for the individual members. Here it's the individual members who have work experience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doubt while using collective nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333153/doubt-while-using-collective-nouns)

Comment: See also https://style.mla.org/verbs-with-collective-nouns/ for a good explanation

Answer (score 1):

"An aging population" is a noun phrase that refers to a specific group of people or individuals who are advancing in age within a particular society or population. Since it is referring to multiple entities collectively, they is the natural choice of pronoun.